# C# Embed Custom Cursor

Tags: c#, resources, cursor

I've spent ages working on this and I've almost got it. However, there is one final problem I am suffering from and it's really starting to get under my skin. I can't embed my custom cursor into my application...

I'm currently using the following method to change the cursor to the custom one I have in the solution explorer. It's "MyCursor.cur", it's an embedded resource and I have set Copy to Output Directory to Copy if Newer. This is the code I'm using to set the cursor:

```
public static Cursor ActuallyLoadCursor(String path)
{
    return new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(path));
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string fileName);
```

and in my form's constructor:

```
Cursor = ActuallyLoadCursor("MyCursor.cur");
```

This is the only thing that has worked for me to load the cursor and use it in my application. This, however, copies the cursor to the same folder as the program. I have searched online for hours with no luck. Is there any way I can do this without it being copied and without a thousand lines of unnecessary code?

Here's other solutions I have tried which have failed for me:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.MyCursor))
{
    Cursor = new Cursor(ms);
}

Cursor = new Cursor(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("My_Namespace.MyCursor.cur"));
```

These resulted in:

> Image format is not valid. The image file may be corrupted.
>   Parameter name: stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your cursor is the right format? Is it a plain 32x32, 1-bit non-animated cursor (created, for example, with the cursor editor in Visual Studio)? According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx) the `Cursor` class only supports the most basic cursor format - animated / color cursors can only be loaded using the Windows API.

I'm asking because I just created a new Windows Form project in VS 2012, added a new cursor, added the cursor to the resources and then used this code:

```
Cursor oC;

using ( MemoryStream oMS = new MemoryStream ( Properties.Resources.Cursor1 ) )
{
    oC = new Cursor ( oMS );

    this.Cursor = oC;
}
```

This works just fine - no errors. (`this` is the form in the code above.)

If your cursor is colored you can still embed it as a resource but you'll have to save it to disk first before loading it using `LoadCursorFromFile`. Don't save the cursor next to your executable - if it's not running from a user's profile folder, you may not have the necessary privileges to create a new file in that folder. Generate a temporary file name in the user's temporary folder (using [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)) and save the cursor data there - once the cursor is loaded, you can delete the file.

Comment: This throws the same error shown above. Although it isn't a 1-bit cursor and wasn't created with the cursor editor in Visual Studio. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @Dragonphase I just edited my answer - if you have a color cursor, you cannot use the `Cursor` class - you have to use the API.

Comment: Either way, I have no idea how to use the cursor editor. The only thing I can use is a magnifying glass. - NVM, controls were hidden

Comment: @Dragonphase Oh, there's a toolbar over the cursor. It's fairly confusing - look for a thick pencil icon to start drawing. You can only pick the colors in the window to the left of the icon drawing. The toolbar only shows up when you open your cursor

Answer (score 0):

My solution without any using a library ...

This section need to be add to beginning of the class:

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.Cursor ActuallyLoadCursor(System.String path) {
        return new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(path));
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern System.IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string path);
```

Call it in the drawing section:

```
this.Cursor = ActuallyLoadCursor(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@"..\..\Resources\cursor.cur");
```